# The APIM gateway couldn't find a public certificate to verify signature

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

we encounter a blocking error during the validation of a JWT token by the gateway.

We are testing an integration environment using two docker containers on two different virtual machines. The first vm contains the APIM 3.0.0 and the second contains the IS 5.9 as Key Manager. The IS is federated with Azure AD.

We obtain a well-formed JWT token by IS with user data from Azure, but the APIM couldn't find a public certificate to verify signature with the given alias. Both wso2 components have their own client-truststore.jks updated with re-created public certificate (we replaced localhost with the public IP of the vms).

Following some useful details:

**This is the error in the log of the APIM container:**

```
[2020-01-30 15:20:00,072]  WARN - SourceHandler I/O error: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
[2020-01-30 15:20:00,404] ERROR - GatewayUtils Couldn't find a public certificate to verify signature with alias ZDgzMWM0MTU3NGI3ODkyYTVkN2Q2N2NmYzI5ZWU4ZjcxYTcyYzlkZA_RS256
[2020-01-30 15:20:00,405] ERROR - APIAuthenticationHandler API authentication failure due to Unclassified Authentication Failure
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APISecurityException: Unclassified Authentication Failure
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.isAuthenticate_aroundBody42(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:433) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_6.5.349.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.isAuthenticate(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:413) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_6.5.349.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.handleRequest_aroundBody36(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:349) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_6.5.349.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.handleRequest(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:320) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_6.5.349.jar:?]
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:366) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcessNonDefaultStrategy(RESTRequestHandler.java:149) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:95) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:71) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:325) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:98) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180) [axis2_1.6.1.wso2v38.jar:?]
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:367) [synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:?]
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:412) [synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:?]
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:181) [synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:?]
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172) [axis2_1.6.1.wso2v38.jar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_222]
```

**Those are the keys provided by https://my_is_ip:my_port/oauth2/jwks:**

```
{
   "keys":[
      {
         "kty":"RSA",
         "e":"AQAB",
         "use":"sig",
         "kid":"ZDgzMWM0MTU3NGI3ODkyYTVkN2Q2N2NmYzI5ZWU4ZjcxYTcyYzlkZA",
         "alg":"RS256",
         "n":"nwcvFrmKaAV3WLgNaronqMHZB5BK7czaRwaKAyM0PTR1KzSa3DJw3CtLtcyz6zvU72JmgFMRyu65H_ly51bCOI6UrpJrKs9bW50fVgjrlqAkCHYIP81s6YgmmLJ-LVZqhAN8g8FH_3b27zbzZ6crspaDmFjSfou4t_A6UTSvQRFbCzp9i5WmQLRHHDy74v9zJWeXCSVA9CknXV4dqpPGMVjJOQzmcaRmZs_rWpdasQUul-D59pY22FrtIziZDLVTerGDGir_dJJboFCzS_DXRch44NJk3cU4lrCcsAP2RXyNhVjJPgmilEnr1aRnxY-WNm_5QKGh37Ez8dLJVVw6LQ"
      },
      {
         "kty":"RSA",
         "e":"AQAB",
         "use":"sig",
         "kid":"ZDgzMWM0MTU3NGI3ODkyYTVkN2Q2N2NmYzI5ZWU4ZjcxYTcyYzlkZA_RS256",
         "alg":"RS256",
         "n":"nwcvFrmKaAV3WLgNaronqMHZB5BK7czaRwaKAyM0PTR1KzSa3DJw3CtLtcyz6zvU72JmgFMRyu65H_ly51bCOI6UrpJrKs9bW50fVgjrlqAkCHYIP81s6YgmmLJ-LVZqhAN8g8FH_3b27zbzZ6crspaDmFjSfou4t_A6UTSvQRFbCzp9i5WmQLRHHDy74v9zJWeXCSVA9CknXV4dqpPGMVjJOQzmcaRmZs_rWpdasQUul-D59pY22FrtIziZDLVTerGDGir_dJJboFCzS_DXRch44NJk3cU4lrCcsAP2RXyNhVjJPgmilEnr1aRnxY-WNm_5QKGh37Ez8dLJVVw6LQ"
      }
   ]
}
```

**This is the result of postman call:**

```
<ams:fault xmlns:ams="http://wso2.org/apimanager/security">
    <ams:code>900900</ams:code>
    <ams:message>Unclassified Authentication Failure</ams:message>
    <ams:description>Unclassified Authentication Failure</ams:description>
</ams:fault>
```

**This is the JWT token:**

HEADER

```
{
  "x5t": "ZDgzMWM0MTU3NGI3ODkyYTVkN2Q2N2NmYzI5ZWU4ZjcxYTcyYzlkZA",
  "kid": "ZDgzMWM0MTU3NGI3ODkyYTVkN2Q2N2NmYzI5ZWU4ZjcxYTcyYzlkZA_RS256",
  "alg": "RS256"
}
```

PAYLOAD

```
{
  "at_hash": "hGnuod6ShKRrlkH_P-k4QA",
  "sub": "d6206844-e54b-4ec2-8ace-26b46da24df2",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "richAccettazionePrivacy": "***************",
  "iss": "https://***************:9443/oauth2/token",
  "given_name": "***************",
  "richAttivazioneCarta": "***************",
  "tid": "962b4d1f-a68b-433e-aa78-265ef05d1047",
  "aud": [
    "dSdZgafomIsRXYQr6XyxIZyjp74a",
    "***************"
  ],
  "nbf": 1580399831,
  "azp": "dSdZgafomIsRXYQr6XyxIZyjp74a",
  "extension_codiceFiscale": "***************",
  "scope": "openid",
  "auth_time": "1580399827",
  "name": "***************",
  "exp": 1580403431,
  "iat": 1580399831,
  "personaId": "***************",
  "family_name": "***************",
  "jti": "c3b8c9bf-029c-4e51-8969-07f898e5654f",
  "email": "***************"
}
```

how to solve this problem?

Comment: So, IS generated this JWT with its new keystore? Did you add that certificate to the gateway's trust store?

Comment: Yes for both. I have also verified that the public certificate imported in the trust stores (apim and is) can verity JWT signature on jwt.io website

Answer (score 0):

> The public certificate of the private key that is used to sign the
>   tokens should be added to the trust store under the
>   "gateway_certificate_alias" alias. For more information, see Import
>   the public certificate into the client trust store.

Ref: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.0.0/Learn/APISecurity/OAuth2/AccessTokenTypes/jwt-tokens/

Comment: Hi Bee, thanks for the reply. I had already imported both public certificate (apim and is) on both trust store as by official instructions, but the problem has always occurred. Besides inspecting trust stores, are there other possible checks?

Answer (score 0):

we solved adding the Identity Server public certificate to the Api Manager client-truststore with alias equal to Kid present in the token header.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see there is no public certificate for alias ZDgzMWM0MTU3NGI3ODkyYTVkN2Q2N2NmYzI5ZWU4ZjcxYTcyYzlkZA_RS256. What you can do is

1. Navigate to the IS_HOME/repository/resources/security/ directory.
2. `keytool -export -alias wso2carbon -file wso2.crt -keystore wso2carbon.jks` run this code in that directory. password is `wso2carbon`.
   This will create a copy of wsp2carbon certificate copy.
3. `keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore client-truststore.jks -alias ZDgzMWM0MTU3NGI3ODkyYTVkN2Q2N2NmYzI5ZWU4ZjcxYTcyYzlkZA_RS256 -file wso2.crt` run this code in API-M_HOME/repository/resources/security/to add wso2carbon public key to trust store.